# Embedded Google Maps tiles not loading in Firefox second page load until zoomed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I am embedding Google Maps for an interactive web application. The map loads fine in Chrome which makes sense. The map has a slightly annoying tile loading issue in Firefox.

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<myApiKey>&callback=onMapInit"></script>
```

In Firefox, the map always loads on first page load or page refreshed. When navigating to the same exact page (second page load?) from say the navbar, the is a high chance that the map tiles don't load like they should and you see gray tiles as shown below.

[image]

Moving the map up or down loads tiles above and below the initial map center but not the original map center.

[image]

The only way to trigger loading the gray tiles is to change the zoom.

[image]

I've tried using the zoom trigger with the following code but it doesn't always work. It also doesn't look the best to have the map zoom in and out every page load.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    internal.map.setZoom(internal.map.getZoom() + 1);

    setTimeout(function() {
        internal.map.setZoom(internal.map.getZoom() - 1);
    }, 200);
}, 200);
```

Is there a way to fix this without an annoying zoom hack?

I've copied the [Google Maps basic sample page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) and added a link at the top that links to itself. This can be tested by saving as an html file and opening in Firefox, clicking the link several times.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
            * element that contains the map. */
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
            /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:5rem;text-align:center">
            <a href=".">Link reference (click me!)</a>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            var map;
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                    zoom: 8
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAa-o55aIMt4YC0mhPyp8WfGql5DVg_fp4&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Would the link to the [live application](https://mattw.io/youtube-geofind/) work? Creating a separate example isn't the easiest because of the required maps API key. That page is on type 'Channel' and clicking 'Channel' in the navbar a couple times should reproduce the gray tiles.

Comment: Use Google's test key, or make the [mcve] and then remove your key from it, once you have verified it reproduces the issue.

Comment: I've copied Google Maps most simple map example and modified it with a link reference to itself at the top. Clicking the link several times reproduces the issue in Firefox.

Comment: I do see a problem with the tiles loading once in a while, but reloading the page again (clicking the link) fixes that. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Yup, that is the issue I was asking about.

Comment: @Waren is there a way to publicly view the issue?  Link you posted requires SSO.

Comment: @Waren I am unable to access the issue publicly as Timestretch has mentioned, appears to require an internal google email/SSO key?

Comment: Sorry about that, try this one instead : https://issuetracker.google.com/138267513.

I've deleted the previous comment to prevent confusion, but I have reported this on the Public Issue Tracker and you can star the bug to get updates.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with Firefox. Loading of tiles is intermittent. If you turn off disk and memory cache in Firefox it works perfectly. If you turn cache back on it continues to have intermittent troubles. I've gotten around this somewhat by listening for the 'tilesloaded' event. If I get this event all is well. This all started a short time after Firefox started blocking Google Analytics by default. Just saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in Firefox 68.0.2, so try the updated one.