# Embedded Google map not completely rendering in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I set up an embedded google map with the Places Autocomplete widget recently and have noticed that in Firefox, the UI renders half the time or not at all. Sometimes I get a blank "gray map of death." The map runs great on Chrome with zero performance issues. Is this a known issue?

My code is based on the Places Autocomplete example in the Google documentation. This below is a saved fiddle from the Maps js developers docs. When I open this in Firefox, It renders with delay or incompletely. If rendered incompletely, and I trigger a search event, the UI loads completely.

https://jsfiddle.net/rcatwr/osza564q/

Most responses to this kind of issue suggest refreshing the map (google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');) or ensuring that the map options are set up correctly (zoom and center). I have investigated these paths. Like I said, It works great in Chrome, poorly in Firefox.

```
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });
  var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
  // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
  // bounds option in the request.
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
  autocomplete.setFields(
      ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
    });
  }

  setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
  setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

  document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
      .addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
        autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
      });
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried to trigger a resize on map idle event, but the problem persists. It's not only the map btw., the autocomplete elements also don't seem to position correctly sometimes.

Comment: Check this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138267513 - I don't know if the last comment is yours...

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported in Google's Issue Tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138267513

It was fixed in Firefox v68.0.2.

Also see related:

[google-places bug in firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57607043/11742502)
[Embedded Google Maps tiles not loading in Firefox second page load until zoomed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57127134/11742502)