# google-places bug in firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I use google-places-autocomplete for fill fields address (address ,city,country,postal code, latittude , longitude) .. it work well in all browsers but it doesen't work everytime in firefox browser (it may caused by the cache firefox browser)
code js:

```
        function initializeAutocomplete(id) {
                    var element = document.getElementById(id);
                    if (element) {
                        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, { types: ['geocode'], language : _mpop.current_lang });
                        if(id == "parent_personal_info_fullAddress" || id == "edit_babysitter_personal_info_fullAddress" ||
                            id == "address_bb" || id == "home_address" ){
                            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', onPlaceChangedEditUser);
                        }
                    }
                }


        function onPlaceChangedEditUser(){
        var place = this.getPlace();
        $('.postal_code').val('');
        for (var i in place.address_components) {
            var component = place.address_components[i];
            for (var j in component.types) {
                var type_element = $('.'+component.types[j]);
                if(component.types[j] == "country"){
                    $('#country').find('option').attr('selected', false);
                    $('#country').find('option[data-country="' + component.short_name + '"]').attr('selected', true);
                    $('#country_iso').val(component.short_name);
                    $('#country').change();
                    $('.country-short').val(component.short_name);


                }
                if (type_element) {
                    type_element.val(component.long_name);
                }
                if($("#latitude").length){
                    $("#latitude").val(place.geometry.location.lat());
                    $("#longitude").val(place.geometry.location.lng());

                }
                if($(".latitude").length){
                    $(".latitude").val(place.geometry.location.lat());
                    $(".longitude").val(place.geometry.location.lng());
                }


            }
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    initializeAutocomplete('babysitter_search_address');
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the map tiles not loading sometimes, this is a known issue that was recently reported in Google's Issue Tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138267513

It appears to have been fixed in v68.0.2. If for some reason you cannot update yet then you can work around this issue by turning off Firefox's cache.

See this other SO thread: [Embedded Google Maps tiles not loading in Firefox second page load until zoomed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57127134/11742502)

Hope this clarifies your question.