# google.maps.event.addDomListener not working with Firefox after second time reload

Tags: jquery, angularjs, firefox, dom, google-maps-api-3

addDomListener not triggered on refresh for the second time in firefox it works with chrome.

How can I fix this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxx&v=3.37"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
   console.log("It Works");
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: `Console.log` isn't valid JavaScript; it should be lowercase: `console.log`. Have you checked the console for errors? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Sorry my mistake with console.log I have updated the question, With logs I don't find any information. So I started to have console with place i am facing issue i can see that the console inside the initialize is not triggered it just skips and goes to next line its not entering initialize in firefox but in chrome i can see it working.

If I do CtrF5 and Disable browser cache it works in firefox.

Comment: Why not do it like it is explained in the docs?

Comment: Its works in chrome without issue only in Firefox for the second time Load event is not triggered dont know why this happens so I directly called $(document).ready( function () { initialize(); }); its working now. Need a solution.

Comment: The one I tried is from the doc you can see its a simple example. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have? This may be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607043/google-places-bug-in-firefox-browser